# Gradle, copy and rename file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to in my gradle script, after creating the bootJar for a spring app, copy and rename the jar that was created to a new name (which will be used in a Dockerfile).  I'm missing how to rename the file (I don't want to have the version in docker version of the output file).

```
bootJar {
    baseName = 'kcentral-app'
    version =  version
}


task buildForDocker(type: Copy){
  from bootJar
  into 'build/libs/docker'
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could directly generate the jar with your expected name, instead of renaming it after it has been generated, using  `archiveName` property from `bootJar` extension:

```
bootJar {
   archiveName "kcentral-app.jar" // <- this overrides the generated jar filename
   baseName = 'kcentral-app'
   version =  version
}
```

**EDIT**
If you need to keep the origin jar filename (containing version), then you can update your `buildForDocker` task definition as follows:

```
task buildForDocker(type: Copy){
    from bootJar
    into 'build/libs/docker'
    rename { String fileName ->
        // a simple way is to remove the "-$version" from the jar filename
        // but you can customize the filename replacement rule as you wish.
        fileName.replace("-$project.version", "")
    }
}
```

For more information, see [Gradle Copy Task DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I do want to first generate the versioned name of the jar, but then want to copy it to another directory with an un-versionsed name.

Comment: Upvoting for your second, edited answer.  Do you think they should be split into two separate answers since they're completely distinct?  — https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210/308327

Answer (score 6):

You can also do something like this:

```
task copyLogConfDebug(type: Copy){
    group = 'local'
    description = 'copy logging conf at level debug to WEB-INF/classes'
    from "www/WEB-INF/conf/log4j2.debug.xml"
    into "www/WEB-INF/classes/"
    rename ('log4j2.debug.xml','log4j2.xml')
```